# Hide rows in DataGridView that match specific criteria

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a requirement that *new* and *deleted* rows should not be visible in a `DataGridView`. I have been able to hide deleted rows, although not in an ideal fashion. I am not able to hide new rows properly, while still being able to alter the bound object in the detail group box which has more information. This makes me suspect I am approaching this problem entirely the wrong way (another indication is that I have searched a lot, but have been unable to find anything specifically like my situation).

### Current approach

I have a `DataGridView` which is bound to a `BindingSource`. The DataSource of this BindingSource is currently a `BindingList<T>` (but I have tried others such as `DataTable` and `DataView`, and using a custom implementation of `IBindingListView`). Additionally, a set of controls (TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, etc) are bound to the Current BindingSource object (see example screenshot below the code). The bound data is from a WCF service, not from a database.

```cs
internal enum PersonState
{
    // New rows that have not been "added" yet. Hide from UI.
    New,

    // New rows that have been "added". These should be saved to the server
    Added,

    // Altered rows. These should be updated on the server
    Edited,

    // Deleted rows. Hide from UI and delete from server when saving.
    Deleted,

    // Do nothing
    Unchanged
}

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // the following properties have code to raise PropertyChanged
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    internal PersonState State { get; set; }
}

public void NewPersonButton_Click()
{
    var person = new Person();
    person.State = PersonState.New;
    personList.Add( person );
}
```

Now, from the example [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdiM4.png); If the user clicks "New", a new instance of the `Person` class is added to the `BindingList<T>` backing the `BindingSource`. It is at this point that they want the row to be hidden in the `DataGridView` (state is **New**), but the user should be able to change the values using the detail group box. Once the user is satisfied (and the information passes validation), the user may click "Add". Only after this step they want to see the row in the `DataGridView` (state changed to **Added**).

### Tested approaches

1. I have tested implementing a custom IBindingListView which will filter the underlying collection (filter any Person objects with State equal to New or Deleted). However, this seems to prevent modification using the detail group box. I tried several approaches to this, e.g. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winformsue/2008/05/19/implementing-multi-column-filtering-on-the-ibindinglistview/
2. I have tested hiding rows using the DataGridView.Rows[i].Visible = false, and manually keeping track of which rows should be hidden/visible. This has the same outcome as the custom IBindingListView, as in there is no way to set a hidden row to the current row. This prevents edits the information in the detail group box.

I don't see any way to achieve this using straight forward binding. I guess what I am asking is; Has anyone achieved something like this using binding? Does anyone have any suggestions for alternative approaches?

Comment: Why not create a property for the `NewPerson` when `New` is clicked, but *not* add it to the list until the user clicks `Add`?

Comment: @OhBeWise I am afraid there is something like this I have to do. To clarify; this means that I have to disable binding for all controls in the group box while this "new" person is edited, and reset binding once the user clicks "Add", or the user selected a different row?

Comment: If you're binding the GroupBox fields to the current row then yes, this may not be as simple as I'd thought.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a    BindingSource that fiters out the rows you dont want?

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

private void SetSource()
{
    bs.DataSource = personList.Where(p=>p.State != PersonState.Deleted && p.State != PersonState.New);
    grid.DataSource = bs;
}

public void NewPersonButton_Click()
{
    var person = new Person();
    person.State = PersonState.New;
    personList.Add( person );
    bs.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

Comment: I have tried something similar, but not exactly this. I will take a look right away.

Comment: Results from attempt: The items are properly hidden from the DataGridView. However, I am not able to edit them in the detail controls. In other words, I can not use this solution by itself.

Comment: Are the detail controls binded to the same bindingsource with the grid?

Comment: Yes they are. I am currently looking into a way to suspend binding while the user control is in the "new entry being created"-state.

Comment: I think you could bind detail controls to another `BindingSource`, where you have the new entry, and then back to main bindingsource

Comment: This actually looks like the best solution I have come across so far! So simple, I can't believe I didn't think of it. I will try this as soon as I get an opportunity and get back to you.